# Do different horses have different speeds?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

All the horses I see available at the different stables cost 1000 gold.  Do they all have similar qualities, or are some faster than others as it was in *Oblivion*?

Comment: I did find a named horse, Frost, areound Riften. Got a quest to steal it, even. Unsure if he's much faster, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> All horses in Skyrim have the same speed and hardiness,they are all draft types that resemble a Clydesdale, and all cost 1000 septims.

Source:
[Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Horse#Horses_in_Skyrim)

Answer (score 8):

There is one horse in Skyrim that, while unable to run faster than regular horses, can sprint further.

> After reaching a certain point in the Dark Brotherhood quest line, you're given access to Shadowmere. Shadowmere seems to be able to sprint for longer distances than regular horses, and is also much harder, if not impossible, to kill.

Comment: The horse referenced in the above spoiler has increased stamina and increased health, but have be killed _[Source: Official strategy guide (book)]_

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are all the same except Shadowmere (acquired after 4/5/3 missions from the Dark Brotherhood. He can climb mountains that other creatures can't (or at least other horses and players).

Comment: Do you have any evidence that Shadowmere can climb mountains that other horses can't?